# "Hot Diggity ..."

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english, expressions, slang

Ok, perhaps the last one was too easy :) Here's one that a friend of mine uses, and I'd love to know if it's something he coined, or is it a more common expression than I think:

> Hot diggity-dag-dong-ding ... sh*t fire and save matches.

Given the southern twang that he uses when he says it, I would imagine this is a southern U.S. saying. Any takers on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a conglomeration of excitement [hot diggity], disbelief/disgust [daggone], and "Well you don't say?"[[sh** fire and save matches](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20fire%20and%20save%20matches)]. Another similar (made up), and idiosyncratic construction:

> Zam a lama durn dang Sh** fire and save the baby!

It is likely highly regional (perhaps to the point of inside his own head).

Comment: Inside his own head = [idiolect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiolect) :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut, as opposed to _out_ of his head, which = crazy. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

Well, Wikipedia has [this to say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Diggity_%28Dog_Ziggity_Boom%29):

> The phrase "hot diggity dog!" dates to at least 1928, when Al Jolson was recorded saying "Hot diggity dog! Hot kitty! Hot pussycat! Didn't I tell you you'd love it?" after a performance of the tune "There's A Rainbow Around My Shoulder".

There was also a song from 1956 called "Hot Diggity (Dog Ziggity Boom)" (same article).

Comment: Oddly enough, I actually remember that song - about 20 years or so before my time, but one of those way back childhood memories.